# Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope - The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Im getting this message in the console when I view the production site. Running locally everything is registers perfectly and all the lighthouse checks pass in chrome dev tools.

Ive tried trouble shooting following the following threads but no luck:
[Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html') Vue js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202273/failed-to-register-a-serviceworker-the-script-has-an-unsupported-mime-type-te)
[Service Worker registration error: Unsupported MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566059/service-worker-registration-error-unsupported-mime-type-text-htm)

Any help would be appreciated as I would really like to run this as a PWA. Here is a link to the full repo
https://github.com/brianlfarmerllc/React_PWA_ReadMeFormatter

I can provide code snippets if that is more helpful

Comment: Please post us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can help you

Comment: Thank you RussellB for the documentation on mcve. The problem actually fixed itself when I push to heroku a second time. Really not sure what the fix/glitch was but it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually fixed itself when I push to heroku a second time. Really not sure what the fix/glitch was but it is resolved.